# Find width and height of RotatedRect

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Refer to [This C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37027329/9134476) I am trying to change in python to do the exact same thing but I am stuck at **for loop to find aspect_ratio**. I am not getting any clue to get the **minimum** and **maximum** **width** and **height** of **RotatedRect** in python as an alternate to **RotatedRect** of **C++** in Python is **cv2.boxPoints**

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Zeeesh/Desktop/1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,200,255,0)
img1,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for contour in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
    (x, y), (width, height), angle = rect
    aspect_ratio = min(width, height) / max(width, height)

    thresh1 = 0.2
    if (aspect_ratio > thresh1):
        print('Straight Line')
        for pt in contour:
            cv2.drawContours(out, [pt], 0,255,0)
    else:
        print('Curve')
        for pt in contour:
            cv2.drawContours(out, [pt], 0,0,255)






plt.imshow(out)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find `width` and `height` of the rotated rect with:

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
(x, y), (width, height), angle = rect
```

Then the aspect ratio is:

```
aspect_ratio = min(width, height) / max(width, height)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. I am trying to find the curve in this                  [This Image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52233166/9134476) but it's giving me an error for this.

Comment: I have edited your code to this as per my problem but it isn't helping me

Comment: above code is edited. Please help me

Comment: Are the width and height in px?

Comment: @Fra yes, of course